GraphQl Hotchocolate, Sending json output canonical with ordered json properties
I have a object that i want to return on my graphql endpoint mutation to the client.
The object that should be returned needs to send canonical json.
{
"data": {
    "signedOutput": {
        "deviceId": "D1",
        "terminalId": "T1",
    }
}

}
my C# class is
public class SignedOutput {
    public string DeviceId { get; set; }
    public string TerminalId { get; set; }
}

but in case my C# object is not nicely ordered due to whatever reason. i would like the output in json to be ordered anyway. Hotchocolate is using System.Text.Json , it's not using Newtonsoft.
Could anyone point it out how i can achieve this?
The graphQl endpoint is as follows
public Task<SignedOutput> SignRequest(
    InputData data,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    var result = new SignedOutput {
        DeviceId = "D1",
        TerminalId = "T1"
    };
    return Task.FromResult(result);
}


You could try use JsonPropertyOrder attribute.
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
...
    public class SignedOutput
    {
        [JsonPropertyOrder(1)]
        public string DeviceId { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyOrder(2)]
        public string TerminalId { get; set; }
    }

